# XCUIElement.typeText() is not typing the correct text because of spelling correction. What can I do?

Tags: spell-checking, xcode-ui-testing

In my UI tests, I want to type some text in a text field which is in a table cell.

So I did this:

```
    let textField = tablesQuery.elementBoundByIndex(index).textFields.elementBoundByIndex(0)
    textField.tap()
    textField.typeText("Snell's Law\r")
```

When I run the test, it successfully found the text field and started typing. But instead of typing "Snell's Law", it typed "said last"!

I think this is due to that annoying spell checking thingy that always pops up.

So I went into the settings, and turn the spell checking off:

[image]

I ran the test and see that it still types "said last"! So I went back to the settings and check whether I have turned spell checking off *properly*.

And to my surprise, the spell checking is indeed off! What is happenning? How can I stop the annoying spell checker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The feature is Auto-correction rather than Spelling correction, which is available on physical devices. In order to prevent the text field from presenting an auto-correct option, you should disable the feature on the text field in your app code/storyboard, if this is a field where autocorrection may not be appropriate, e.g. A search field.

Auto-correction works well for natural language fields for free-flowing text, but not as well for simple, short phrases.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [SBTUITestTunnel](https://github.com/Subito-it/SBTUITestTunnel). This framework extends UI Test's adding several features (net mocking, remote code invocation) among which you can also disable UITextfields autocomplete for a specific test.

Once you install the framework, you would fire up the application in your test target like this:

```
func testExample() {
    let app = SBTUITunneledApplication()
    app.launchTunnelWithOptions([SBTUITunneledApplicationLaunchOptionDisableUITextFieldAutocomplete]) {
         // do additional setup before the app launches, if needed

    }

    // From here on UITextField's autocomplete will be disabled   
}
```